# theiconic php-ga localhost vhost page views doesn't show up

Tags: php, google-analytics

Okay, so I setup a google analytics account for testing purposes. I have to work on some stuff and I'm testing things locally before pushing it to our live environment. Since the tracking has to be done if Javascript is off we use the php-ga-measurement-protocol library from theiconic.

This is the code I use:

```
$this->analytics = new Analytics(true, false);
$this->analytics->setClientId(filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, 'gaClientId', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))
->setDebug(true)
->setDocumentHostName(getenv('HTTP_HOST'))
->setDocumentLocationUrl(getenv('HTTP_HOST') . getenv('REQUEST_URI'))
->setDocumentPath(getenv('REQUEST_URI'))
->setIpOverride(getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP') ?: getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') ?: getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
->setProtocolVersion('1')
->setTrackingId({TRACKING_ID})
->setUserAgentOverride(getenv('HTTP_USER_AGENT'))
->setUserLanguage(strtolower(substr(getenv('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 5)));
```

The URL generated would look something like:

https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?cid=g9m2nds3980dki4ia2rcivtjn3&dh={WEBSITE.LOCAL}&dl={WEBSITE.LOCAL}%2F&dp=%2F&uip=127.0.0.1&v=1&tid=|||&ua=Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Windows%20NT%206.3%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64%29%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome%2F74.0.3729.157%20Safari%2F537.36&ul=en-us&dt={DOCUMENT_TITLE}

This is the response:

```
{
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?cid=g9m2nds3980dki4ia2rcivtjn3\u0026dh={WEBSITE.LOCAL}\u0026dl={WEBSITE.LOCAL}%2F\u0026dp=%2F\u0026uip=127.0.0.1\u0026v=1\u0026tid=|||\u0026ua=Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Windows%20NT%206.3%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64%29%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome%2F74.0.3729.157%20Safari%2F537.36\u0026ul=en-us\u0026dt={DOCUMENT_TITLE}?_anon_uip=127.0.0.0"
} ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

However, going to my Google Analytics page, it doesn't show up an active user and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't that the intended consequence of sending the hit with debug mode "on"? To validate that the hit is correctly formed, but not to actually record the hit and impact reporting? From your own code:

```
->setDebug(true)
```

```
"hit": "/debug/collect?cid=g9m2nd..."
```

From the Google [hit validation documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits) on the `/debug/collect` endpoint:

> **Important**: hits sent to the Measurement Protocol Validation Server will not show up in reports. They are for debugging only.

Comment: Oops, I guess I never read the documentation properly. I think I was doing something wrong and I enabled debug because before the hits wouldn't show up, but it turned out I forgot to change the tracking ID (cause I was using the one from our live environment). But I never removed debug and I thought it would just work. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I've definitely done something similar before; totally understandable.